# iOS: Detecting touch down, segue, touch up

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

1. User puts her finger on the screen. This triggers a `UITouchEvent`, phase `Began`, which calls the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method in `controllerA`, which performs a segue from `controllerA` to `controllerB`.
2. User lifts her finger off the screen. This triggers a `UITouchEvent`, phase `Ended`, which calls some callback method.

Question: What and where is this callback method? It's not in `controllerA`, and it's not in `controllerB`. From what I can tell, it's not in any view. But it exists.

Comment: Cant you do a NSLOG in the VC A for touches released ? Pretty sure thats going to be the one thats called.

Comment: No, as I already mentioned, it's not called in either controller.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Passing parameters from on fire to another, when the segue is performed?

Comment: Added a clarification.

Comment: Any ideas? This seems like a really common problem.

Comment: do you mean for touchsEnded delegate method of UITouch

Comment: @Tsubaki I'm not sure how common this problem would be. The generally accepted practice is to perform actions like segues after the touch has ended using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` or some such equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, here's what's going on (according to @switz):

- In response to `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`, a view controller is presented
  modally via a segue
- When the user lifts up their finger, the view controller should be dismissed.

The question is how to react to the finger being lifted, since
`-touchesEnded:withEvent:` is not invoked.

The short answer is the presented view controller needs to use the "Over Full
Screen" `modalPresentationStyle` instead of the default "Full Screen" style
(this can either be specified as the presentation style of the segue, or if
that's "Default" then the presentation style of the presented view controller).

The long answer requires a brief overview of how touch handling works. This
explanation ignores gesture recognizers:

When a touch begins, it's delivered to the "topmost" view that contains the
touch point. From there it gets passed along the responder chain until some
object decides to handle the touch (which is signified by implementing
`-touchesBegan:withEvent:` and not calling `super`).

Subsequent changes to the touch (e.g. moved, ended, canceled) are delivered back
to the same view that accepted the touch. The view will continue to receive the
touch events until the touch finishes or cancels.

A touch is canceled either when the application moves to the background (because
e.g. a phone call came in), or when a UIKit class like `UIScrollView` decides
that it needs to take over touch handling (because the finger moved far enough
that it looks like the user wants to scroll). There's also some funny stuff here
with `UIScrollView.delaysContentTouches`, but that can be ignored.

But there's a wrinkle, something that isn't documented: touch delivery only
happens so long as the view remains associated with the window. If the view that
is considered "topmost" (the view that is associated with the `UITouch`) is
removed from the window, then the touch is considered to have vanished and,
importantly, no events for that touch are delivered again, to anyone. This is
true even if the view in question is not the object handling touches.

And that final wrinkle is the cause for this problem. Because the default
"Full Screen" presentation style actually *removes* the old view controller's
view from the window, the touch handling immediately stops. However, the "Over
Full Screen" presentation style does not remove it, it merely covers up the old
view with the one. "Over Full Screen" is typically used when the presented view
controller is not fully opaque, but in this case we're using it so touch
handling isn't interrupted.

---

But that's not all. There's another problem here, which is when the view that's
being touched lives inside a `UIScrollView` (one that either is scrollable or
always bounces). In that case, even with "Over Full Screen", you'll find that,
while the touch events continue to be delivered, moving your finger around a bit
suddenly causes the touch to be canceled. This is because the `UIScrollView`
doesn't know it's covered up and has decided that the user is actually trying to
scroll. This causes it to cancel the touch.

There is a solution to this, though. It's kind of ugly, but the solution is to
immediately cancel any scrolling on any enclosing scroll view when performing
the segue. This can be done with code like the following:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // this is called from -touchesBegan:withEvent: from a child view
    // the child view is `sender`
    func touchDown(sender: UIView) {
        var view = sender.superview
        while view != nil {
            if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
                // toggle the panGestureRecognizer enabled state to immediately
                // cause it to fail.
                let enabled = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled
                scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
                scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = enabled
            }
            view = view?.superview
        }
        performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: self)
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

Of course, no discussion of touch handling would be complete without gesture
recognizers. Gesture recognizers change pretty much everything about touch
handling. They get first dibs on any touches, and they can interrupt view touch
handling at any time. For example, the `UIScrollView`'s `UIPanGestureRecognizer`
is what is used for scrolling, and when it moves into the "began" state (because
the user has moved their finger enough), that's what causes the touch to be
canceled.

So given this, really the best solution here is to not implement
`-touchesBegan:withEvent:` at all, but to use a gesture recognizer. The easiest
solution here is to use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with
`minimumPressDuration` set to `0` and `allowableMovement` set to some
ridiculously high value (since you don't want movement to cancel the touch). I'm
recommending this because `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is a continuous
recognizer, meaning it will send events for Began, Moved, and Ended, and with
the recommended settings, it will send them in response to the touch beginning,
moving, and ending. What's more, once your recognizer starts handling the touch,
this automatically prevents any other recognizers (such as the scroll view's pan
recognizer) from "taking over" and canceling the touch.

---

Note that if you're attaching your gesture recognizer to the scrollView itself
(e.g. a `UITableView`) but only want to respond to touches in certain locations
(such as on a row), then you'll need to restrict the recognizer. You can use the
delegate method `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceiveTouch:)` to do this, something
like this:

```swift
func gestureRecognizer(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    // if you might be the delegate of multiple recognizers, check for that
    // here. This code will assume `recognizer` is the correct recognizer.
    // We're also assuming, for the purposes of this code, that we're a
    // UITableViewController and want to only capture touches on rows in the
    // first section.
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touchLocation) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            // we're on one of the special rows
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This way the recognizer won't prevent the `tableView`'s `panGestureRecognizer`
from scrolling when the user touches elsewhere on the table.

Comment: As an FYI - I modified the long press minimum duration to `0.1` and checked `if (recognizer != yourLongPressGestureRecognizer) { return true }`  which gives the scroll recognizer precedence over your long press. This lets users scroll fairly easily while still allowing a seamless "press and hold". Also, if you have an accessory button, you can detect if your press is on the far right. `if fingerLocation.x > self.tableView.bounds.size.width - 40 { // accessory tap }`